# What tag export formats are there?

Tags: tags, export, file-format

I'm writing an importer for a CMS to import tags from various platforms/sources. I want to be able to import tags from WordPress, Moveable Type, Blogger; basically all of the big boys.

Are there any generic, standard tag export formats?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question, I'd assume you're looking for a common format that all of the big boys export to, which can then be consumed by your application. From what I can see, WordPress eXtended RSS appears to be pseudo-supported amongst WordPress, Movable Type, and Blogger. You might want to consider reading here for more information:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content

This link does double duty for your question, since it also provides a comprehensive list of common blog engines, their export assumptions, and what formats you should consider supporting.

As for the WXR file format itself, it seems to be quite difficult to find a specification for in both Google and WordPress' own search database. Here's the most relevant result I could find:
http://olalindberg.com/blog/2008/12/13/write-your-own-wxr-file-to-migrate-custom-cms-to-wordpress

Good luck!